# Uploaded an image to AWS S3 using boto3. It gets downloaded when the URL is clicked

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
bucketName = "player-img"
file = '59.png'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
object_acl = s3.ObjectAcl(bucketName,file)
response = object_acl.put(ACL='public-read')
```

This is how I uploaded an image named `59.png` to my Bucket.
However, when I click the URL (`https://player-img.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/59.png`), it gets downloaded instead of going to the image URL. How can I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "This is how I uploaded an image"? The code you show does not perform an upload. It simply references an existing object stored in Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `Content-Type` of the file. You can do it via AWS Console (Select file in the bucket -> Properties -> Metadata). It should be `image/png` or similar. You can set `Content-Type` either manually on the same page or when you upload the file with boto:

```
s3bucket.put_object(Key='59.png', Body=data, ContentType='image/png')
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you add `/59.png` in url, it will obviously be downloaded. Remove image file name component from url

Comment: How would I access the image if I remove the file name?

Comment: You want to go to url where image exists. That means you want to go to the bucket. If you hit the inage url, it will download it for you.

Comment: Will there be no issues if I just put the link into `img src`?